# Splitting Single Column value in to three Column values for a report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, common-table-expression, sql-query-store

For Example

I have below Scenario Can any one suggest on this 
Current Scenario

```
Col1 
-----
Test1
Test2
test3  
Test4
Test5
Test6
test7
Test8
Test9
Test10
test11
Test12
```

Expected scenario

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
-------------------
Test1  Test2  Test3         
Test4  Test5  Test6
test7  Test8  Test9
Test10 Test11 test12
```

...
Goes on

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iflHZ.png)

Comment: What exactly you want? Your question is not well formatted. Please format it.

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: I need to dispay as below  Col 1 must contain 1  4 7 10  Col2 must contain 2 5 8 11 Col3 must contain 3 6 9 12

Comment: Please check the image description Thanks

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 3 = 0 then col end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 1 then col end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum % 3 = 2 then col end) as col3   
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by col) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 3)
order by min(seqnum);
```

This adds a sequential number and then uses arithmetic and `group by` to reduce the number of rows.

Comment: No when i have 20 data the data is not working .only for 10 Data it is working fine. After 11 th Data it position to diferent and gives the wrong out put .kindly guide me

Comment: @KumaranN . . . This puts the additional data in additional rows.

Comment: Great Thanks . Gordon Linoff. its mistake on our Side We exporting in to Different package .Query works fine But Deployed and when imported to SAP it throws an error now it is resolved thank you.